# PHP: Why my Mail() Functions are not working?

Tags: php, server, smtp, cpanel

Hi I am trying to test my PHP mail function but it is not working. I have shared hosting all of my website mail function are not working

```
<?PHP
$sender = 'xx@gmail.com';
$recipient = 'xx@gmail.com';

$subject = "php mail test";
$message = "php test message";
$headers = 'From:' . $sender;

if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo "Message accepted";
}
else
{
    echo "Error: Message not accepted";
}
?>
```

I have also checked my php.ini if mail function is disabled but it is not disabled

```
disable_functions =
```

I also tried using Easy WP SMTP Plugin. But it is not working. I am sure that my settings are correct.

But this is what i got

```html
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Thank you

Comment: *I have shared hosting all of my website mail function  are not working.* ... Usually the hosting provider has a FAQ for what if any thing special to code in to get mail to work on the PHP side. Most times they have an example of PHP code for making mail work. Check the "knowledge base" or do a search on your hosting provider's site on how to do mail.

Comment: Hi @GetSet Thank you for your response. I am using WHM . They are working yesterday . But when I restarted my server . It suddenly didn't work.

Comment: Network problem. Firewall is blocking those ports. Surprised it's blocking the SSL port as well. Once you resolve that, you should be good to go. As an alternative, you could change the port on the SMTP server to a custom port that your provider will allow you to use (25000, 25252, etc).